# Angular 2 - Reloading a component onChange

Tags: angular

Need help regarding Angular 2 and how to reload a component within a component.

So I have a NavbarComponent which contains a translation dropdown menu. All translation are i18n json format. When I select a language the translation happens correctly. My project is structured like this

```
app
|-----Categories
      |-----categories.component/module/routing/service/html
|-----Users
      |-----users.component/module/routing/service/html
|-----navbar.component/html
|-----app.component/module/routing
```

I am not going to list the full structure, but if you need it I can put it in full.

Now, like I said all static translation happens fine. I have a section in categories, which connects to a python api, and retrieves data in json format, this returns the data based on the language selected.

What I need is, when the language is changed from the dropdown in the NavbarComponent, as it translates the page, it also request a new set of data from the python api with the language selected and load it within the container (without refreshing the page).

So far I can make the request, but I can make the request, but I do not know how to push the data in the CategoriesComponent for it to update the HTML. Code below.

navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from 'ng2-translate';
import {CategoriesService} from "./categories/categories.service";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";
import {CategoriesComponent} from "./categories/categories.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: 'app/navbar.component.html',
    directives: [CategoriesComponent]
})
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {
    categories: any[];
    busy: Subscription;
    private url: string;
    public supportLanguages: any[];
    myCall: string;
    constructor(private translate: TranslateService, public     categoriesService: CategoriesService) {
    }

    ngOnInit (){
        this.supportLanguages = [ {'display':'English', 'value': 'en'},
                              {'display':'Français', 'value':'fr'},
                              {'display':'中文', 'value':'zh'},
                              {'display':'Español', 'value':'es'} ];

        this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
        this.translate.use(this.translate.getDefaultLang());
    }

    isCurrentLang(lang: string) {
    return lang === this.translate.currentLang;
    }

    setLang(lang: string){
        this.myCall = "Hello World";
        this.translate.setDefaultLang(lang);
        this.translate.use(this.translate.getDefaultLang());
        this.url = "http://localhost:8000/category/type/list?lang_id=" + this.translate.getDefaultLang();
        this.busy =     this.categoriesService.getCategoriesType(this.url).subscribe(categories =>     this.categories = categories);
    }
}
```

categories.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { CategoriesService } from './categories.service';
import {TranslateService} from "ng2-translate";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/categories/categories.component.html'
})
export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
    categories: any[];
    busy: Subscription;
    myCall: string;
    private url: string;

    constructor(private _categoriesService: CategoriesService, private translate: TranslateService){
        this.translate.use(this.translate.getDefaultLang());
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.url = "http://localhost:8000/category/type/list?lang_id=" + this.translate.getDefaultLang();
        console.log(this.url);
        this.busy = this._categoriesService.getCategoriesType(this.url).subscribe(categories => this.categories = categories);
        this.translate.use(this.translate.getDefaultLang());
    }
}
```

I hope somebody can help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider to write a 'LanguageService' to which every component could subscribe for language-updates (e.g. with rxjs Subject). Inject this service into 'NavbarComponent' and 'CategoriesComponent', subscribe for changes and reload your data.

Answer (score 0):

Like Thomas said, you could make a translation service which handles all the translations separately.

Another interesting idea would be to make a pipe, and in that pipe hit your python api with  the data.  The only major constraint is that you must throttle the requests. For example:

```
{{ stringToTranslate | translate:'spanish'}}
```

You can check the angular 2 docs for how to create/use pipes if you are unsure.